# How to convert constrainted optimization problem to an unconstrained one?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose I have an optimization problem

$$ \mathbf{w}^* = \max_{\mathbf{w}} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_i - \mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x}_i)^2 $$
$$\text{subject to}$$ 
$$\sum_{j=1}^m w_j^2 \leq \tau$$

I want to show this can be written as

$$ \mathbf{w}^* = \max_{\mathbf{w}} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_i - \mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x}_i)^2 + \lambda \sum_{j=1}^m w_j^2$$

What is the basic intuition behind this?

I have done basic Lagrangian multiplier problems like

$$\max_{\mathbf{x}} U(\mathbf{x})$$
$$\text{subject to}$$ 
$$\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{w} = \tau$$

In those cases, I have written a Lagrangian like

$$L(\mathbf{x},\lambda) = U(\mathbf{x}) + \lambda (m - \mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{w})$$

But there's two issues:

1. A Lagrangian isn't itself something I minimize, correct? I am trying to rewrite my constrained problem as an unconstrained problem.
2. There is an inequality, not an equality. I assume the Kuhn-Tucker conditions are relevant to this, but I am not sure how.

Comment: if an optimal solution to your original problem exists, what you want to show follows trivially from Lagrange duality (although determining $\lambda$ is not trivial).

Comment: @LinAlg What information could I add to this post that would make it more answerable but that also wouldn't be like posting the original problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know what you are looking for. Lagrange duality means $\min_x \max_\lambda L(x,\lambda) = \max_\lambda \min_x L(x,\lambda)$, and you are rewriting the formulation on the left hand side to the one on the right hand side.

Comment: I've updated the question with a related one that will hopefully be more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Introducing the slack variable $\epsilon$ you can write the unconstrained equivalent optimization problem with the Lagrangian

$$
L(\mathbf{w},\lambda,\epsilon) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_i - \mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x}_i)^2 + \lambda \left(\sum_{j=1}^m w_j^2-\tau + \epsilon^2\right)
$$

NOTES

1) Solving the lagrangian we will have it's stationary points which should be qualified.

2) Analyzing the the values for $\epsilon^*, \lambda^*$ we can conclude the K-T conditions.